# create a folder structure with name and date +7 days

Tags: powershell, date, batch-file, directory, subdirectory

i want to create a folder name with a start of W1 09-09-2021 (this is the name of the folder)
i want the second one to be W2 + 7 days is there a way to create that in batch ? for let say 6 months ?
Regards

Comment: Yes it possible ;P What have you tried so far? [mre] ? Hint: `(Get-Date 09-09-2021).AddDays(7)` (Powershell)

Comment: hello i try to use mkdir command to create w1 and so on but cannot find a way to do it in batch :-(

Comment: hello i found a way to create the folder name mkdir $(1..20 | %{"W$_"})   but how to add the date next to it and on folder to add 7 days

Comment: Why did you use a date which nobody but you, could be sure of the format? Is it `W$_ dd-MM-yyyy`, or `W$_ MM-dd-yyyy`? Could you please also explain how batch-file is related to your question? because your above comment clearly shows that you're using powershell. Please also do not add code to the comments, [edit] your question to include it properly formatted.

Comment: Since when does Week number 1 start at 09-09-2021 ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this. The could be more compressed but since you're a beginner I believe will learn more if I leave it like this.

Remember to update the `$folderPath` variable using the destination Full Path where the new folders should be created.

```
$startDate = [datetime]'09-09-2021'
$endDate = $startDate.AddMonths(6)
$startWeek = 1
$folderPath = "X:\fullPath\to\newFolders"
$datesToExclude = @(
    '12-30-2021' # This will Exclude 30 of December 2021
) | ForEach-Object {$_ -as [datetime]}

do
{   
    if($startDate -notin $datesToExclude)
    {
        $folderName = "W{0} {1}" -f $startWeek, $startDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
        $newFolderPath = Join-Path $folderPath -ChildPath $folderName
        New-Item $newFolderPath -ItemType Directory
    }

    $startDate = $startDate.AddDays(7)
    $startWeek++

}until($startDate -ge $endDate)
```

New folders should look like this from **W1** until **W26**:

```
W1 09-09-2021
W2 09-16-2021
W3 09-23-2021
W4 09-30-2021
...
...
...
W24 02-17-2022
W25 02-24-2022
W26 03-03-2022
```

Comment: if im already in the correct folder should i just discard the path ?

Comment: @PierreAuger If your current directory is the same as where the folders will be created you can set the variable to a `dot` like this: `$folderPath = "."`

Comment: thanks alot it work great  one more thing can we exclude some date to be created like the 30 of december ?

Comment: one more thing it start on the 16 i want the first folder to be w1 on 09-09-2021 i try to play with start date but it keep starting at 16

Comment: @PierreAuger yeah it is, I edited the code. Just update the variable `$datesToExclude` use a `DateTime` format like what I'm doing for testing. If the answer was helpful to you and solved your problem, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Comment: whe do you add $datesToExclude ?

Comment: something like that :  $startDate = [datetime]'02-09-2021'
$endDate = $startDate.AddMonths(6)
$datesToExclude = 30-12-2021
$startWeek = 1
$folderPath = "."

do
{
    $startDate = $startDate.AddDays(7)
    $folderName = "W{0} {1}" -f $startWeek, $startDate.ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
    $newFolderPath = Join-Path $folderPath -ChildPath $folderName
    $startWeek++

    New-Item $newFolderPath -ItemType Directory

}until($startDate -ge $endDate)

Comment: @PierreAuger please read the edited code, the answer is there, you just need to update the `$datesToExclude` variable. Regarding  ***"i want the first folder to be w1 on 09-09-2021"***, this was my bad and should be fixed now.

Comment: it work ty except the dates to exclude but i will found out TY

Comment: @PierreAuger ok, last edit, see my comment in the code. I only added `'12-30-2021'` to be excluded but you can add multiple dates there using the same `Date Format`.

Comment: THANKS alot Santiago

Comment: @PierreAuger no problem, happy to help :)